# Python 3 - Error in printing *args using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python 3 by watching a series of tutorials,
In one of these videos which is about optional function arguments (`*args`), the instructor uses a for loop to print the optional parameters passed to the function (the tuple).

When I try to run the instructor's script, I get an error:

---

Instructor's script:

```
def test(a,b,c,*args):  
    print (a,b,c)  
for n in args:  
    print(n, end=' ')  

test('aa','bb','cc',1,2,3,4)
```

OUTPUT:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe C:/untitled/0506.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:/untitled/0506.py", line 4, in <module>  
    for n in args: print(n, end=' ')  
NameError: name 'args' is not defined  

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

```
def test(a,b,c,*args):  
    print (a,b,c)  
    print (args)  

test('aa','bb','cc',1,2,3,4)
```

OUTPUT:

```
aa bb cc  
(1, 2, 3, 4)  
Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

What's causing the error?
P.S: I'm using Python 3.3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got your indentation wrong:

```
def test(a,b,c,*args):  
    print (a,b,c)  
    for n in args:  
        print(n, end=' ')  

test('aa','bb','cc',1,2,3,4)
```

Indentation is significant in Python; your version declared the `for n in args:` loop *outside* of the `test()` function, so it was run immediately. Since `args` is a local variable to `test()` only, it is not defined outside of the function and you get a `NameError`.